# how to change the output from Unity Display dialog to specific Gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, unity-editor

I am a beginner in programming so I need to know the following: I am calling REST APIs from my project to the server, and I am stuck here.

I am trying to show the output of my button on specific Gameobject in my Scene. I want to know how many UnityEditor properties are there or how to point my game object for an output instead of DialogDisplay popup?

```
EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Posts", JsonHelper.ArrayToJsonString(res, true), "Ok");
return RestClient.GetArray(basePath + "/todos");
}).Then(res => {
EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Todos", JsonHelper.ArrayToJsonString(res, true), "Ok");
return RestClient.GetArray(basePath + "/users");
}).Then(res => {
EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Users", JsonHelper.ArrayToJsonString(res, true), "Ok");
```

the name of my GameObject is Output

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very basic example on how to use *[EditorUtility.DisplayDialog](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.DisplayDialog.html)* from Unity documentation

```
// Places the selected Objects on the surface of a terrain.

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class PlaceSelectionOnSurface : ScriptableObject
{
    [MenuItem("Example/Place Selection On Surface")]
    static void CreateWizard()
    {
        Transform[] transforms = Selection.GetTransforms(SelectionMode.Deep |
                SelectionMode.ExcludePrefab | SelectionMode.Editable);

        if (transforms.Length > 0 &&
            EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Place Selection On Surface?",
                "Are you sure you want to place " + transforms.Length
                + " on the surface?", "Place", "Do Not Place"))
        {
            foreach (Transform transform in transforms)
            {
                RaycastHit hit;
                if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, out hit))
                {
                    transform.position = hit.point;
                    Vector3 randomized = Random.onUnitSphere;
                    randomized = new Vector3(randomized.x, 0F, randomized.z);
                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(randomized, hit.normal);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I think you can make something like that and access the object using Selection.gameobjects which get you a list of the selected game objects then you can can do any thing with them.

```
GameObject[] objects = Selection.gameObjects;
if (EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Title", "Msg", "Ok"))
{
    Debug.Log(objects[0]);

    // ... //
}
```

Comment: Thanks Waleed for the Information. But i need to change exactly the from the Editor Utility to Game Object because the Display Dialog is a part of Unity UI and i am not using Unity UI i am using Hololens UI Button and for the that i dont know how should i change the script accordingly.

Comment: So your question is about how to display UI in Unity with buttons and do something when you click that button right?

Comment: Yes but specifically for specific buttons Holographic Button so for example i want to do specially

Comment: So this button should be called and display should be available on the UI TEXT PREFAB but Editor Utility is allowing right now to display on Unity UI but not allowing on Holographic buttons. 


how can make change it from Unity UI to Holographic Buttons